# How to know why/when an application crashed on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, crash, logging

I am using Windchill with Catia on Windows XP SP2. I am facing Catia V5 crashes heavily but I don't know why. I am using only the recommended graphic drivers.

Please help me out. How can I know what is the reason for catia crashes? I want to record logs to know why catia is crashing.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking `Event Viewer` in Windows see what events are being logged when it crashes.  You can get to this by going to Start > Run > and typing `eventvwr.msc`.

Comment: The log will only tell "how", not "why".

Answer (score 0):

As Tim S. Van Haren said, Event Viewer is your best chance at finding this information out.

It's entirely up to the application to report that. On crashing, an application could choose to report "why" it crashed, or it could report nothing at all.

That said, **no application crashes on purpose**, and more often than not, some software bug makes things interact wrong with your hardware. Finding out *why* an application crashed is challenging even for developers, and it's rare to ever just be given the answer. If it knew why, it probably could have prevented the crash in the first place.